# vlc uwp Dash playback issue

Tags: c#, uwp, vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I'm using VLC for Instagram live playback.
As long as I'm using `Libvlcsharp 3.4.6 VideoLAN.libvlc.UWP 3.1.1.1` everything working fine when I create a media from the live dash playback URL.
But when I update any of the NuGets above live playbacks can not play anymore and I see only a black screen.
I have to mention that, the latest UWP VLC player from Windows Store can play the URL, I don't know what is going wrong.
Thanks.
Regards

Comment: Please open a bug report at https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libvlcsharp with the full logs.

Comment: how can I get logs of VLC?

Comment: Have a look at the troubleshooting section of the LibVLCSharp documentationon the github repository